# Handle command line argument value from in-memory / inject content instead of use cli argument

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, luks

Is there a way to handle command line arguments from in-memory?
My concrete problem is, I have a volume encrypted with luks, with a detached header file.

Setup as following:

- workstation
- server

I don't want to store the header file on the the *server*, so I keep it on *workstation*.
When I want to decrypt the luks volume, I want to issue a simple ssh command from the other machine, without storing the header file on the *server* For example:

```
sh
ssh root@server.lan "cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mdx/ --header=... volume1"
```

Is there a way to keep the header file locally on *workstation*, and only transfer the content of the file over the ssh connection, which are handled on the *server* side and treated as local file argument?

The problem here (as I understand it), is that `cryptsetup` opens and reads the file specified as `--header`. Is there a Linux/UNIX way to fake this, and "push/inject" the content of the file into the command?

Currently I'm using a USB stick, where the header is stored.

I hope it's clear what I want, English is not my native language, perhaps something got lost in translation.

---

EDIT: What about a temp/ram-fs where is store/copy the file to after each reboot?
I just discoverd that there is default tempfs, `/dev/shm` is it safe to use it?

Comment: I can confirm that I regularly use `/dev/shm` in a production environment to store files that are generated on reboot. Why do you think it isn't safe?

Comment: I was just curious, perhaps its importanted for the system, and i dont want to mess things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/dev/shm` file system is designed for shared memory. As explained in [this Cyberciti article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html):

> /dev/shm is nothing but implementation of traditional shared memory concept. It is an efficient means of passing data between programs. One program will create a memory portion, which other processes (if permitted) can access. This will result into speeding up things on Linux.

Just like `/tmp` which is also a tmpfs file system on modern Linuxes, anything you store there will be kept in memory and will be deleted on reboot. However, I don't know of any reason why you can't use `/dev/shm` for storing files that you want to have accessible. And I can confirm that in the place I work, we regularly use `/dev/shm` on our production systems to store a set of files that will be used by many programs and which are created on each boot.

So I would say you can go right ahead and store the file there on every boot if that is a working solution to your problem.

Comment: I will try it out, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use process substitution, `<(command)`. This is replaced with a transient filename that represents a pipe containing the output of the command.

```
ssh root@server.lan cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mdx/ --header=<(cat) volume1 < /path/to/headerfile
```

Comment: Thats freaking awesome! I tried it with `ssh root@server.lan "echo <(cat) /dev/shm" < /dev/shm/text.txt` from *workstation.lan* where i issued before `vim /dev/shm/text.txt` and put "Hello World" into the file. After the command i had a textfile on *server.lan* `/dev/shm/text.txt` with the content "Hello World", i try it tomorow with the real header/setup.

Comment: I don't see how that's creating a file on the server. Did you mean`echo <(cat) > /dev/shm/text.text`?

Comment: @Barmer Do you have time for a chat? -> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/130173/1678189?tab=general

Comment: Sorry, not at the moment